# Azure DevOps migration how to fix error VS403300

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Trying to migrate from TFS to Azure DevOps, the collection is too big to import using a DACPAC, so I have created a VM in Azure as per the guidance, but when I try to import I get the following error:

> [Error] VS403300: It appears that your Azure VM is located in SUK. It’s required that customers targeting UKS for import must have their
>   Azure VMs in UKS. Please move or create an Azure VM in UKS and
>   re-queue the import.

I am trying to migrate to UK South and the VM is in that region.

Answer (score 0):

If this VM originally created in SUK and moved to UKS, you're going to need to update the public facing IP address for the VM to be in UKS. Otherwise the IP filter is going to not allow the import.

Comment: The server was created in UK South and hasn't been moved. I don't know a way to create a VM using the 3 letter region code and selected UK South creates in SUK rather than UKS.

Answer (score 0):

@user11516518, this issue seems on our(Microsoft) side. Make sure the public facing IP address to be in UKS(United Kingdom South), and also if your VM has firewall, try with **making your firewall point out UKS** .

If issue could not be solved after these try, recommend you report your issues here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=22
The engineer of our team can help you investigate and solve this issue.

Comment: Share some details about your VM while you report this to our team, which can help us locate the log correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The error message was a bug in the import tool, Microsoft issued a fix on 27th May 2019. If you try again it should behave as expected now.